# for loop not performing with object

Tags: javascript, object, for-loop, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm using Canvas to play and learn with Javascript. Currently I'm creating a circle and have it display in random areas on the screen. I was able to complete that exercise completely; everything ran smoothly in one function.

Now I would like to create an object for the circle and call it in the for loop. I created the object, but something is still wrong. I'm only seeing one circle instead of 40. I banged my head on this for awhile before coming here for help. Take a look at the code below.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

if (!ctx) {
  alert('HTML5 Canvas is not supported in you browser');
}

function Circle(posX, posY, radius, startAngle, endAngle, anticlockwise) {
    this.posX = posX;
    this.posY = posY;
    this.radius = radius;
    this.startAngle = startAngle;
    this.endAngle = endAngle;
    this.anticlockwise = anticlockwise;

    this.test = function() {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(posX, posY, radius, startAngle, endAngle, anticlockwise);
        ctx.fill();
  }
}

var cir = new Circle(
    (Math.random() * canvas.width),
    (Math.random() * canvas.height),
    20,
    0,
    Math.PI*2,
    true
);

function drawCircle() {
        for(var i = 0; i < 40; i++){
        cir.test(); 

        }
}

/*setInterval(drawCircle, 400)*/
 drawCircle();
```

Comment: lol you're drawing 40 circles on top of each other, because you're calling `cir.test()` and the `posX` and `posY` and the rest of the properties are not changing

Comment: You are calling `cir.test()` 40 times without having 40 instances of `Circle`. It is the same circle being drawn 40 times on top of itself.

Comment: Don't mind @Edwin, we were all there once

Comment: I saw in console the circle drawing 40 times but was stumped as to why because it worked fine before consolidating the circle into an object. I guess objects are what I need to understand better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `cir.test()` 40 times without having 40 instances of Circle. It is the same circle being drawn 40 times on top of itself.

This might be an immediate fix to your problem:

```
function drawCircle() {
        for(var i = 0; i < 40; i++){
            // Mind you that doing this
            // Will not allow you to reference
            // your circles after they are
            // created. The best method is 
            // to put them in an array
            // of circles
            var cir = new Circle(
                (Math.random() * canvas.width),
                (Math.random() * canvas.height),
                20,
                0,
                Math.PI*2,
                true
            );

            cir.test();
        }
}

/*setInterval(drawCircle, 400)*/
 drawCircle();
```

However, I would recommend the following changes to your code:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

if (!ctx) {
  alert('HTML5 Canvas is not supported in you browser');
}

function Circle(posX, posY, radius, startAngle, endAngle, anticlockwise) {
    this.posX = posX;
    this.posY = posY;
    this.radius = radius;
    this.startAngle = startAngle;
    this.endAngle = endAngle;
    this.anticlockwise = anticlockwise;

    // Using better function names
    // is always a good idea
    this.testDraw = function() {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(posX, posY, radius, startAngle, endAngle, anticlockwise);
        ctx.fill();
  }
}

// Create an array to fill
// with Circle instances
var circlesArray = []

// Changed drawCircle to drawCircles
// it is clearer
function drawCircles() {
    for(var i = 0; i < 40; i++){
        // Create new Circle objects
        // and add them to the circlesArray
        // this will allow you to have a
        // each circle later on
        circlesArray.push(new Circle(
            (Math.random() * canvas.width),
            (Math.random() * canvas.height),
            20,
            0,
            Math.PI*2,
            true
        ));

        // Go through each item of the array
        // and call the test function
        circlesArray[i].testDraw();
    }
}

/*setInterval(drawCircle, 400)*/
 drawCircles();
```

Comment: Thank your. your explanations were clear and I learned a lot. I was really close to solving it with the first example, but gave up a little too early I guess. The second example is something I really need to read up on; creating arrays and pushing items into it.

Answer (score 0):

Currently your drawCircle() function is running a single test function on the same 'cir' variable 40 times. What you want to do is to fill an array with 40 new items using the for-loop. Then, use another for-loop to define those items as new Circle objects and call the test function on each new circle.
Here is the code I would use:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

if (!ctx) {
  alert('HTML5 Canvas is not supported in you browser');
}

function Circle(posX, posY, radius, startAngle, endAngle, anticlockwise) {
  this.posX = posX;
  this.posY = posY;
  this.radius = radius;
  this.startAngle = startAngle;
  this.endAngle = endAngle;
  this.anticlockwise = anticlockwise;

  this.test = function() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(posX, posY, radius, startAngle, endAngle, anticlockwise);
    ctx.fill();
  }
}

/*Create an array to hold your circles*/
var circleArray = [];

function drawCircle() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
    circleArray.push('cirlce' + i); /*Push circle variable into circleArray*/
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < circleArray.length; i++) {
    /*Create a new circle object for every iteration of the circleArray*/
    circleArray[i] = new Circle(
      (Math.random() * canvas.width), (Math.random() * canvas.height),
      20,
      0,
      Math.PI * 2,
      true
    );
    circleArray[i].test(); /*Run the test function for every item in the circle array*/
  }
}

/*setInterval(drawCircle, 400)*/
drawCircle();
```

```html
<canvas id='canvas'></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please read the comments, if you need more help understanding this just comment below.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

if (!ctx) {
  alert('HTML5 Canvas is not supported in you browser');
}
//The only thing I can see perhaps changing is radius so use radius as parameter
function Circle(radius) {
    this.posX = Math.random() * canvas.width; //This is always going to be the same so no need to pass as an argument
    this.posY = Math.random() * canvas.height; //So will this
    this.test = function() {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(this.posX, this.posY, radius, 0, Math.PI*2, true); //So will Math.PI*2, and true
        ctx.fill();
    }
    this.test();
}

function drawCircle() {
    for(var i = 0; i < 40; i++){
        new Circle(i); //This passes i as the radius so you can see the differences
    }
}

drawCircle();
```